# Proving a graph does not have a hamilton circuit

Tags: graph-theory, hamiltonicity

[image]

Hello, I am trying to prove that this graph does not have a Hamilton circuit. The only thing I know is that all vertices of degree 2 must have all their edges in the circuit, however this does not prove to be useful. Are there any other useful observations that can be made?

Comment: there is no edge between R and W

Comment: The vertices $V,X,Y,Q$ have an **odd** number of edges starting from them. Too many...

Comment: @dan_fulea You're thinking of Eulerian, not Hamiltonian.

Comment: QPVTS must be consecutive, so make them one big point, and you have a simpler system with only five points left

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There's two approaches here.

The first is to start from where you started from: the degree-$2$ vertices ($T$ and $P$) must all have their edges in the Hamiltonian cycle. Once you draw those edges, you can keep going with some other vertices. For example, you'll see that vertex $Y$ (which has $3$ edges) can no longer use one of them, so it must use the other two. Repeat until you paint yourself into a corner.

The second is a problem of global structure. The graph is bipartite. Identify how, and then figure out why this prevents a Hamiltonian cycle from existing.

Comment: Ahh thanks so much. I was able to implement both of these methods and understand them.

Answer (score 1):

Removing the $4$-subset $\{Q,S,V,X\}$ yields $5$ connected components.  Because $4<5$, this subset provides a certificate that the graph does not contain a Hamiltonian cycle.